# System.configuration.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute is not valid on this attribute type

Tags: c#

I just converted a solution to C#.  And I guess the AssemblyInfo.cs is not working and I'm not sure why.  Here's a snippet from that class...there are more sections in the AssemblyInfo.cs that I need to fix like the below example section:

```
namespace InstantASP.Common.Application
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides reflection methods for working with and obtaining information from .NET assemblies.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public class AssemblyInfo
    {



[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyDelaySign(false)]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("")]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyName("")]
...
```

I get the errors with the assembly attributes [assembly:  or whatever these are above.  I am not familiar with this so I do not know how to fix this.

Do I even need this class?

Answer (score 0):

In my web application there is no namespace and no class. May be you need to remove the namespace and the class. It should look like:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle( "MyTitle" )]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription( "" )]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration( "" )]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany( "MyCompany" )]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct( "MyProduct" )]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright( "Copyright © MyCompany 2011" )]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark( "" )]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture( "" )]

[assembly: ComVisible( false )]

[assembly: Guid( "3d5900ae-111a-45be-96b3-d9e4606ca790" )]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion( "2.6.*" )]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion( "1.0.0.0" )]
```